# Install postgresql with Homebrew does not work

Tags: postgresql, homebrew

I tried to install PostgreSQL on my mac book with homebrew.

```
brew install postgresql
```

But I couldn't install it and got these error messages.
Does anyone know what is the solution for this issue?

```
./formatted_string_builder.h:227:9: note: subexpression not valid in a constant expression
        U_ASSERT(category <= 0xf),
        ^
../common/uassert.h:35:26: note: expanded from macro 'U_ASSERT'
#   define U_ASSERT(exp) void()
                         ^
./formatted_string_builder.h:240:64: note: in call to 'Field(0, 1)'
constexpr FormattedStringBuilder::Field kGeneralNumericField = {UFIELD_CATEGORY_UNDEFINED, 1};                                    
                                                                ^

3 errors generated.
*** Failed compilation command follows: ----------------------------------------------------------
clang++ -DU_ATTRIBUTE_DEPRECATED= -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_HAVE_STRTOD_L=1 -DU_HAVE_XLOCALE_H=1 -DU_HAVE_STRING_VIEW=1 -I. -I../common -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -std=c++11 -Qunused-arguments -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wglobal-constructors -fvisibility=hidden -fno-common -c -MMD -MT numfmt.d numfmt.o numfmt.ao -o numfmt.ao numfmt.cpp
--- ( rebuild with "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make VERBOSE=1 all" to show all parameters ) --------
make[1]: *** [numfmt.ao] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 2

Do not report this issue to Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core!


Error: You are using macOS 10.12.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You will encounter build failures with some formulae.
Please create pull requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub,
Discourse, Twitter or IRC. You are responsible for resolving any issues you
experience while you are running this old version.
```

Comment: I am also having this issue. Another error that appears for me when i try to run the command is "curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: Invalid certificate chain
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html". Are you getting that as well?

Comment: So far I have only this error message not like "SSL certificate problem".
Could you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need icu4c, The currently the version of icu4c written in Homebrew's Fomula is 67.1, and macOS is required to be **High Sierra (10.13)** or higher.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I am currently using Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6, so I need to update it.
Sorry, I am not familiar with icu4c. Does it mean I need to install updated version?

Comment: @user14035795 u just need to update your mac os to 10.13 or higher

Comment: Actually, after I updated my mac os to Catalina, I still can't install postgresql for my rails project... (at least I could install postgresql)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63893342/gem-install-pg-fails