# gem install pg fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rubygems, pg

I have created new Ruby on Rails project and when I tried to connect the server with the "rails s" command, I have an error that says `Could not find gem 'pg (>= 0.18, < 2.0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.`

So I decided to install pg gem with "gem install pg" but got another huge error message:

```
 ERROR:  Error installing pg:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

 current directory: /Users/kota/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/ext
/Users/kota/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/bin/ruby -I /Users/kota/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r ./siteconf20200914-24744-m9qarh.rb extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/local/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... yes
checking for PQsetSingleRowMode()... yes
checking for PQconninfo()... yes
checking for PQsslAttribute()... yes
checking for PQresultVerboseErrorMessage()... yes
checking for PQencryptPasswordConn()... yes
checking for PQresultMemorySize()... yes
checking for timegm()... yes
checking for rb_gc_adjust_memory_usage()... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for C99 variable length arrays... yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/kota/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/ext
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/kota/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/ext
make "DESTDIR="
compiling gvl_wrappers.c
compiling pg.c
compiling pg_binary_decoder.c
compiling pg_binary_encoder.c
compiling pg_coder.c
pg_coder.c:216:34: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        res = this->dec_func(this, val, RSTRING_LEN(argv[0]), tuple, field, ENCODING_GET(argv[0]));
              ~~~~                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/kota/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1007:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING_EMBED_LEN(str) : \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/kota/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1003:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_EMBED_LEN'
     (long)((RBASIC(str)->flags >> RSTRING_EMBED_LEN_SHIFT) & \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pg_coder.c:216:34: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        res = this->dec_func(this, val, RSTRING_LEN(argv[0]), tuple, field, ENCODING_GET(argv[0]));
              ~~~~                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/kota/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1008:28: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING(str)->as.heap.len)
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
2 warnings generated.
compiling pg_connection.c
compiling pg_copy_coder.c
pg_copy_coder.c:228:15: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                                        strlen = RSTRING_LEN(subint);
                                               ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/kota/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1007:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING_EMBED_LEN(str) : \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/kota/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1003:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_EMBED_LEN'
     (long)((RBASIC(str)->flags >> RSTRING_EMBED_LEN_SHIFT) & \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pg_copy_coder.c:228:15: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                                        strlen = RSTRING_LEN(subint);
                                               ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/kota/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1008:28: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING(str)->as.heap.len)
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
pg_copy_coder.c:534:23: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                input_len = end_ptr - start_ptr;
                          ~ ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
3 warnings generated.
compiling pg_errors.c
compiling pg_record_coder.c
pg_record_coder.c:196:15: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                                        strlen = RSTRING_LEN(subint);
                                               ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/kota/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1007:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING_EMBED_LEN(str) : \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/kota/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1003:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_EMBED_LEN'
     (long)((RBASIC(str)->flags >> RSTRING_EMBED_LEN_SHIFT) & \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pg_record_coder.c:196:15: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                                        strlen = RSTRING_LEN(subint);
                                               ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/kota/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1008:28: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING(str)->as.heap.len)
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
2 warnings generated.
compiling pg_result.c
compiling pg_text_decoder.c
compiling pg_text_encoder.c
pg_text_encoder.c:194:14: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                        len = out - start;
                            ~ ~~~~^~~~~~~
pg_text_encoder.c:406:15: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                return optr - out;
                ~~~~~~ ~~~~~^~~~~
pg_text_encoder.c:410:12: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                return 2 + RSTRING_LEN(*intermediate) * 2;
                ~~~~~~ ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pg_text_encoder.c:617:13: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        nr_elems = RARRAY_LEN(value);
                 ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/kota/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1070:23: note: expanded from macro 'RARRAY_LEN'
#define RARRAY_LEN(a) rb_array_len(a)
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
4 warnings generated.
compiling pg_tuple.c
pg_tuple.c:482:15: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        num_fields = RARRAY_LEN(values);
                   ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/kota/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1070:23: note: expanded from macro 'RARRAY_LEN'
#define RARRAY_LEN(a) rb_array_len(a)
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
compiling pg_type_map.c
compiling pg_type_map_all_strings.c
compiling pg_type_map_by_class.c
compiling pg_type_map_by_column.c
pg_type_map_by_column.c:161:52: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        return dec_func( p_coder, RSTRING_PTR(field_str), RSTRING_LEN(field_str), 0, fieldno, enc_idx );
               ~~~~~~~~                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/kota/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1007:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING_EMBED_LEN(str) : \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/kota/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1003:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_EMBED_LEN'
     (long)((RBASIC(str)->flags >> RSTRING_EMBED_LEN_SHIFT) & \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pg_type_map_by_column.c:161:52: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        return dec_func( p_coder, RSTRING_PTR(field_str), RSTRING_LEN(field_str), 0, fieldno, enc_idx );
               ~~~~~~~~                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/kota/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1008:28: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING(str)->as.heap.len)
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
pg_type_map_by_column.c:230:17: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        conv_ary_len = RARRAY_LEN(conv_ary);
                     ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/kota/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1070:23: note: expanded from macro 'RARRAY_LEN'
#define RARRAY_LEN(a) rb_array_len(a)
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
3 warnings generated.
compiling pg_type_map_by_mri_type.c
compiling pg_type_map_by_oid.c
compiling pg_type_map_in_ruby.c
compiling pg_util.c
pg_util.c:119:24: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        return (char*)out_ptr - out;
        ~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
1 warning generated.
linking shared-object pg_ext.bundle
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib'

current directory: /Users/kota/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/ext
make "DESTDIR=" install
make: /usr/local/opt/coreutils/bin/gmkdir: No such file or directory
make: *** [.sitearchdir.time] Error 1

make install failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/kota/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/pg-1.2.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/kota/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.7.0/pg-1.2.3/gem_make.out
```

I have already installed Postgresql with brew.

my Ruby version: ruby 2.7.0p0

my rails version: Rails 6.0.3.3

Comment: What version of macOS command line tools? If v12 beta then downgrade to 11.5 and try again.

Comment: Do you mean xcode-select --version?
It says xcode-select version 2373

Comment: actually my xcode is xcode 11.7

Comment: have you run ```bundle install```?

Comment: Yes, but when I tried ```bundle install``` I got another error:

```An error occurred while installing nio4r (2.5.3), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install nio4r -v '2.5.3' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  rails was resolved to 6.0.3.3, which depends on
    actioncable was resolved to 6.0.3.3, which depends on
      nio4r```

Comment: follow the instrution ```gem install nio4r -v '2.5.3' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'``` and find what error raised

Comment: `gmkdir` is a GNU utility which just runs `mkdir -p` and is made for windows compatibility reasons. You might be able to get it to work by running `brew install coreutils` or by just creating an alias of mkdir.

Comment: brew install coreutils works! 
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on linux machine, then install the postgresql-devel package  using command

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

If you are using macosx, then

```
brew install libpq
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/libpq/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```